# ClientError: ENA must be supported with uefi boot-mode

Tags: windows-10, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a Windows 10 Home VM in Amazon EC2. The plan is to run it in EC2 for about two days, our partner will access it through RDP and then I will transfer it back to VirtualBox. I prepared the image in VirtualBox, then exported .ova file, uploaded it to S3 and tried to convert it to AMI with following command as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/what-is-vmimport.html).

```
$ aws ec2 import-image --description "Windows 10 VM" --platform Windows --disk-containers "file://foo/containers.json" --boot-mode uefi --license-type BYOL --architecture x86_64
```

But I get following error after the import process reaches progress 27%:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids fooID
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "Description": "Windows 10 VM",
            "ImportTaskId": "fooID",
            "LicenseType": "BYOL",
            "Platform": "Windows",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "DiskImageSize": 8298251264.0,
                    "Format": "VMDK",
                    "Status": "completed",
                    "Url": "s3://foo/Windows-10.ova",
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "foo",
                        "S3Key": "Windows-10.ova"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError: ENA must be supported with uefi boot-mode",
            "Tags": [],
            "BootMode": "uefi"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have done these steps:

1. [Installed ENA driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html#ena-adapter-driver-versions) (Didn't help)
2. [Installed AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) (Didn't help)

What should I do? I know for sure that the VM boots using UEFI in VBox. Should I convert it to BIOS boot? Is there anything I need to install or what? Google returns only [this thread](https://repost.aws/questions/QUqKQIF1cdQrq6h3hb8yJYiw/does-aws-support-windows-11-ec-2-instances) which is unanswered and they are talking about instance types. So I asked my own question [here](https://repost.aws/questions/QUJbR6AqiOSU2rHHkkyGEB0w/client-error-ena-must-be-supported-with-uefi-boot-mode) and this one you are reading right now because I feel like SuperUser comunity is much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/launch-instance-with-uefi-sb.html

Currently not supported.

(Some more characters)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter `--boot-mode legacy-bios`.

Comment: Would you care to [edit] and expand upon your answer and explain why and where this parameter is used? Also please take the [tour] to get a better understanding of how SE/SU works.

Comment: But it is not only about parameter or is it? I guess I can not use legacy-bios if the drive contains UEFI bootloader.

Comment: Although yes I end up using BIOS boot mode but with clean Windows install which really used BIOS boot mode. I guess that 15 years old technology is too bleeding edge for AWS. That's probably why they doesn't offer Windows 11.